# Is general anesthesia safe for critical patients?

Tags: trauma, anesthesia

Take the example of a trauma patient who has lost a lot of blood and slipping into unconsciousness.

Is giving him general anesthesia during surgery risky? or is it has no real impact on the outcome?

Is the reason behind anesthesia only to avoid discomfort to the patient from operation even in critical cases?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.